# Reading in a UNICODE "file" from the resource area

Tags: xml, visual-c++, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to determine the correct way of reading in an XML file from the resource area to be converted to a `bstr_t` to be passed on to an XML converter.

This is what my workmates and I have so far:

```
bstr_t LoadXMLFromResource(UINT id)
{
    HINSTANCE hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    HRSRC hrSrc = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), _T("XML"));
    CStringW strXML;

    if (hrSrc)
    {
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hInst, hrSrc);
        if (hGlobal)
        {
            LPVOID xmlBuffer = LockResource(hGlobal);
            LPUTF8 leftAngleBracket;
            leftAngleBracket = strchr((LPUTF8)xmlBuffer, '<');  // skip over BOM if exists
            if (leftAngleBracket)
                strXML = leftAngleBracket;
            UnlockResource(hGlobal);
        }
        FreeResource(hGlobal);
    }

    return bstr_t(strXML);
}
```

I'm a little concerned about using the `LPUTF8`.  This was originally because the file was a `UTF-8` file, but there is some concern with some conversion issues/redundancy, so we are considering moving to `UTF-16`.  But it is still a bit unclear to me.  Also, the first line in our XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

which of course will change if we go to `UTF-16`.

**Notepad** save as dialogue allows for saving: `UTF-8`, `Unicode` or `Unicode big endian`.

**VS2013** save as dialogue allows for saving: `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`, `Unicode - Codepage 1200` and `Unicode (Big Endian) - Codepage 1201`.  That first entry actually is dependent on if the original has a BOM or not.  If without a BOM, it will say `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage ???` I don't remember what the codepage it stated was.  It shows one or the other, never both.  Confused yet? o.O

So, if we use a *Unicode* encoding which is not `UTF-8`, what do we state on the first line of the XML file?  From what I've been reading, [UNICODE is *not* `UTF-16`](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

I'm thoroughly confused with what Windows calls Unicode and the `UTF-x` standards.

For reference, here is the source that is calling this function:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr m_pXml;

m_pXml.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
m_pXml->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXml->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXml->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;
VARIANT_BOOL bRet = m_pXml->loadXML(LoadXMLFromResource(resouceId));
```

So to recap, my question is, what is the "best" way to read an XML file from the resource with the least amount of conversions/allocations? Although it is probably not a big deal if it does it a few times, but I need some metric to give to the rest of the team to state why one way is better than another.  If you have some other metric, please feel free to chime in.

A secondary question would be, what is the first line to say in the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best might be you let the XmlDocument deal with encodings, and don't try to do anything fancy about them yourself (thus your code will automatically support all encoding msxml supports, and you won't need to care how the source files are encoded). Means, you could just read the resource as a *binary data blob* and then feed that to the XmlDocument (as IStream).

Like this:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = AfxGetResourceHandle();
HRSRC hrSrc = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), _T("XML"));

HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hInst, hrSrc);

LPVOID xmlBuffer = LockResource(hGlobal);
ULONG xmlBufferSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hrSrc);


// read the resource into a memory stream as data blob
LPSTREAM pStream = NULL;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &pStream);
pStream->Write(xmlBuffer, xmlBufferSize, NULL);
LARGE_INTEGER pos = { 0 };  // rewind
pStream->Seek(pos, 0, NULL);

MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr m_pXml;

m_pXml.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
m_pXml->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXml->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXml->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;

// here we go: load the document from the binary stream
VARIANT_BOOL bRet = m_pXml->load(pStream);
```

Comment: This sounds so awesome! I'd like to know though, since your not using IStreamPtr, does that mean I have to call `pStream->Release()`?  And was there a reason why you didn't use `CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, &pStream)`?  From the documentation I found, it should init the stream to that value which would result in one less copy, right?

Comment: Ok, I understand why you can't pass the `hGlobal` as it is not truly an `HGLOBAL`, but what about calling `pStream->Release()`? Should I instead use `IStreamPtr`?

Comment: yes, the code misses the pStream->Release, you need to call it, or you can just use IStreamPtr, it will call the Release automatically for you. I would say you can simply return IStreamPtr from the LoadXMLFromResource() function (instead of bstr_t you currently have)

Comment: I have changed the raw pointer in the code sample with IStreamPtr - you are right, it will be better this way.

Comment: If you do that, then the `m_pXml->Load(pStream)` becomes `m_pXml->load(pStream.GetInterfacePtr())`.  This is great.  I'm also tweaking this to use `IStreamPtr pStream = SHCreateMemStream(xmlBuffer, xmlBufferSize);` instead.  No need to write the data to the stream, it is initialized that way.  I understand that there are some MT issues prior to Win8, but this isn't an issue for me.  Thanks! Oh, one other thing is you forgot to unlock the `hGlobal`.

Comment: One last thing.  I found out that `IStreamPtr pStream = SHCreateMemStream(xmlBuffer, xmlBufferSize)` is incorrect. It should be `pStream.Attach(SHCreateMemStream(buffer, bufferSize))` or a memory leak will occur.  This doesn't occur with the call to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`.